# Bootstrap modal not displaying after close

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

When i display and close modal window, after click on button modal window not display again. Screen is grayed out and content of modal window not show.

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

```html
function pipedriveshortcode() {
    ob_start();
    
    
   ?>


<a type="button" class="filterbutton" href="#myModal1" data-toggle="modal">BOOK FREE ADVISORY </a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal1" class="modal" tabindex="-1">

<div 
<section class="vc_section block-form-pipoedrive"><div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid"><div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-12"><div class="vc_column-inner"><div class="wpb_wrapper">
 <div class="wpb_raw_code wpb_content_element wpb_raw_html ">
  <div class="wpb_wrapper">
   <span class="close" data-dismiss="modal"></span>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="wpb_raw_code wpb_content_element wpb_raw_html">
  <div class="wpb_wrapper">
   <div class="pipedriveWebForms" data-pd-webforms="https://pipedrivewebforms.com/form/xxxxx" id="idd8ptf" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; min-width: 320px; position: relative;"><script src="https://cdn.pipedriveassets.com/web-form-assets/webforms.min.js"></script>
<div class="asd"></div>
<iframe src="https://pipedrivewebforms.com/form/xxxxx?embeded=1&amp;uuid=idd8ptf" scrolling="no" name="http://whalebone.g6.cz/telecom/-idd8ptf" style="border: none; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; max-width: 768px; min-width: 320px; height: 1003px; position: relative;"></iframe></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div></div></div></div></section>
   </div> </div>   
   </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
 </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->

    <?php

    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('pipedrive', 'pipedriveshortcode');
```

Comment: I can't see any pronlem to open close in snippet

Comment: Neither can I. Just use your snippet...

Comment: What browser (and version) do you experience the issue on?

Comment: Google chrome. Modal window not display for the second time.

Comment: can it be related to php hook? This snippet is for WordPress shortcode: function pipedriveshortcode() {
    ob_start();
    
    
   ?> *****snippet*****<?php

    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('pipedrive', 'pipedriveshortcode');

Answer (score 0):

Some improvement is required in your `html` and you also need to specify the `data-toggle="modal"` along with `data-target="#myModal1"`

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<a type="button" class="filterbutton" href="#myModal1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">Launch demo modal</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal1" class="modal" tabindex="-1">

  <section class="vc_section block-form-pipoedrive">
    <div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid">
      <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-12">
        <div class="vc_column-inner">
          <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <div class="wpb_raw_code wpb_content_element wpb_raw_html ">
              <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                <span class="close" data-dismiss="modal">Close</span>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="wpb_raw_code wpb_content_element wpb_raw_html">
              <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                <div class="pipedriveWebForms" data-pd-webforms="https://pipedrivewebforms.com/form/xxxxx" id="idd8ptf" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; min-width: 320px; position: relative;">
                  <script src="https://cdn.pipedriveassets.com/web-form-assets/webforms.min.js"></script>
                  <div class="asd"></div>
                  <iframe src="https://pipedrivewebforms.com/form/xxxxx?embeded=1&amp;uuid=idd8ptf" scrolling="no" name="http://whalebone.g6.cz/telecom/-idd8ptf" style="border: none; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; max-width: 768px; min-width: 320px; height: 1003px; position: relative;"></iframe>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
```

Comment: On website nothing changed. After second click window not display and page only grayed out: https://ctrlv.cz/shots/2020/06/09/CvAf.png

Comment: I updated snippet - this HTML is inside php file. Can it be related?

Comment: have you copied my snippet html and replace it with yours?

Answer (score 0):

here's the code i use for modals:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <b>Title</b>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

           Body of modal!

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This code work perfect, but how to remove all this Bootstrap styles? I need instead this my own styles as in my snippet.

Comment: maybe play around with them one at a time until you find the right look & feel

Comment: I pasted code under class="modal-body" and it show correctly, but for the second time is modal empty

Comment: First correctly displayed: https://ctrlv.cz/shots/2020/06/09/xQsc.png Second click: https://ctrlv.cz/shots/2020/06/09/FeIc.png

Comment: is the data getting changed between times you show it?

Comment: Yes "<div <section="" class="vc_section block-form-pipoedrive">" changed on <div <section="" class="vc_section block-form-pipoedrive hidden-form">